# Search query not returning partial queries

Tags: mysql, search, match

I can't seem to get a working search query going... This is my current query. (which someone just gave me)

```
SELECT MATCH (username, first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('$search') AS relevance, DISTINCT(auto), user_id, username, first_name, last_name, email, sex, active, ppic, time_zone, adult_filter, ((CASE WHEN `username` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `first_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `last_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS relevance
    FROM users, network WHERE MATCH (username, first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC, username
```

Which works, except that it will not return partial matches, which is what I need to happen.

Here is my old query...

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(auto), user_id, username, first_name, last_name, email, sex, active, ppic, time_zone, adult_filter, ((CASE WHEN `username` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `first_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN `last_name` LIKE '%$search%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS relevance
FROM users, network
WHERE `username` LIKE '%$search%' OR
  `last_name`LIKE '%$search%' 
  OR `first_name` LIKE '%$search%' 
ORDER BY relevance DESC, username LIMIT 5
```

Which returns partial values... except it breaks when you have multiple words. (so it is working for searching "john" but not "john smith")

I've spent two days going through search queries to find one to fit my needs, and have yet to be able to do it. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (as in how to get it to work with partial words and multiple words).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE `username` LIKE '%$search%' OR
      CONCAT(`first_name`,' ',`last_name`) LIKE '%$search%'
```

This tries to match
- `$search` against `username` field
- `$search` against `first_name last_name`.

However, it won't safe-guard against (say) if `$search` is `John  Smith` (two spaces), etc - you might want to somehow normalise the search term on the code side before assigning it to `$search` (for example, convert all occurences of two or more spaces in a row to one space).

Comment: Well that definitely helped, but I don't like that it is restricting the names like that... for example if I were to search a username and their full name then it won't come up... Isn't there a way I could just search all sections and the result with the most matches in the combined number of sections gets placed first...?

Comment: The only way I can think of is you do heaps of `OR CONCAT(...) LIKE '%$search%'` to cover all combinations: `firstname lastname username`, `firstname username lastname`, `lastname firstname username`, `lastname username firstname`, etc..